# How to continue append the new record into text file without replace the old record (Java)

Tags: java, io, printwriter

**My problem now is when I append the new record, it will replace the old one.**

Below is the block of code which write all the input I get from the textbox to the **text file**:

```
try{

    PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("LogFile.txt");
    p.print("USERNAME\tROLE\t\tACTION\t\tLOGON_TIME\n");
    p.print(AcademicSystem.user.getLogin_username() + "\t\t");
    p.print(AcademicSystem.user.getRole()+ "\t");
    p.print("Login" + "\t\t");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMM/yyyy hh:mm:s");
    p.print(simpleformat.format(cal.getTime())+ "\n");
    p.println();
    p.close();
    
}catch(Exception er){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,er);
}
```

*This is the main class:*

```
 Scanner lg = new Scanner(new File("LogFile.txt"));
            while(lg.hasNext()){
                lg.nextLine();
```

Output in the text file:

```
USERNAME    ROLE        ACTION      LOGON_TIME
a           Lecturer     Login      21/August/2020 03:17:2
```

*Thus, what isthe solution which I need to do, if I want the program is able to continue append the new record to the text file?*

Comment: You have to open the file in append mode. ``PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Logfile.txt", true));``

Comment: @NomadMaker, please upgrade your comment to an answer.

Comment: BTW @KongJason note how your example code snippets include not a single Swing or AWT class? That's a red flag that indicates that the tags are not appropriate to this problem, since it was not related to those packages. Think longer on the tags in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Open the file in append mode.**

Normally opening a file overwrites whatever data there was in the original file. However, if you open a FileOutputStream with a filename and a boolean of true, it will append the new data after the original data.

`FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(String filename, boolean append)`

To open the PrintWriter like it was originally opened, use the line:

`PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Logfile.txt", true));`

Then you can write to the file and new data will be appended to the original file.